# how to make chat window like skype in android in a Tabbed base application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, chat, tableview

This may be a very newbie question but i am not getting that how to build one simple `multi user chat` application having multiple chat windows separate for each user. I am building one `Tabbed` based application [***This***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy2aX.png) having multiple `Tabs`(5). Home Tab have `google map` having pins of my nearby(according to settings) fans & three `ImageButtons` on the top, *list button* shows me the `MapPins` as a list.`Messages` tab have list of all fans  [***this***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LqEe.png) to whom i can `Chat`.

What i need is when i click on any item of fan list then one [`ChatWindow`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pZ9L.png) will opened (separate for each user that can be switched from one to another) on the same tab, & having three buttons on the top *list button* to navigate back to fan list, *delete button* to remove chat history & *close button* to close current chat window respactively, same as this one new chat window is opened on every click of fan list item if the fan`s chat window is not already opened or if i am going to chat with the new fan. I follow [Marc Reichelt's](http://marcreichelt.blogspot.in/2010/09/android-use-realviewswitcher-to-switch.html) blog to switch between these multiple `ChatWindows` views like the home screen does. Thanks to @Marc Reichelt for such an awesome blog.

how do i build the layout that have three button on the top that are fixed & multiple chat windows below it that can be switched...**?**

I build one [***`Test-ChatWindow`***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90A6E.png) by following Marc

`my code is ->`

```
public class MultipleChatWindows extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 /** Class that extends ViewGroup */
 RealViewSwitcher realViewSwitcher;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // create the view switcher
    realViewSwitcher = new RealViewSwitcher(getApplicationContext());

    final int[] backgroundColors = { Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN,
            Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        TextView dateTime = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        dateTime.setTag("time" + i);
        dateTime.setTextSize(15);
        dateTime.setHint("Date & Time");
        //dateTime.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
        dateTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        dateTime.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        dateTime.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);

        ScrollView scVw = new ScrollView(this);
        scVw.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        scVw.setTag("chat_scVw" + i);
        // scVw.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320, 300));// 320,380
         scVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
        table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);
        table.setTag("chat_table" + i);
        //table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        table.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        //table.setWeightSum(1);
        table.setSelected(true);
        table.setScrollBarStyle(ScrollView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET);
        //table.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
        rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        TableRow rowConditions = new TableRow(this);
        rowConditions.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        TextView title = new TextView(this);//
        title.setText("ManU CHAT Window" + i);

        title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
        title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        title.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        /* If i add the table on scroll view then when i add one new row in this table view by clicking 
         * on send button & try to scroll on to next chat window then it will not give me the touch listener 
         * which is call when i touch on the scroll view. that`s why i directly add table on to main view 
         * behalf of adding this scroll view but it create one problem that is when the given size of the
         * table is filed by the rows then it will not scrolled... How do enable scrolling on it???   */
         scVw.addView(table);
        //table.addView(scVw);

        LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(this);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        main.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColors[i]);
        main.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        main.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        LinearLayout chatChild = new LinearLayout(this);
        chatChild.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        chatChild.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        //chatChild.setWeightSum(1);

        EditText chatMessage = new EditText(this);
        chatMessage.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        chatMessage.setTag("chat_msg_text" + i);
        chatMessage.setSingleLine();
        chatMessage.setHint("Type your Message");

        Button sendMessage = new Button(this);
        sendMessage.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        sendMessage.setId(i);
        sendMessage.setTag("chat_send_btn" + i);
        sendMessage.setText("Send");

        sendMessage.setOnClickListener(this);

        chatChild.addView(chatMessage);
        chatChild.addView(sendMessage);

        main.addView(dateTime);
        main.addView(scVw);
        //main.addView(table);
        main.addView(chatChild);

        realViewSwitcher.addView(main);

    }

    // set as content view
    setContentView(realViewSwitcher);

    // OPTIONAL: listen for screen changes
    realViewSwitcher.setOnScreenSwitchListener(onScreenSwitchListener);

 }

 private final RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener onScreenSwitchListener = new RealViewSwitcher.OnScreenSwitchListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScreenSwitched(int screen) {
        // this method is executed if a screen has been activated, i.e. the
        // screen is completely visible
        // and the animation has stopped (might be useful for removing /
        // adding new views)
        Log.d("RealViewSwitcher", "switched to screen:" + screen);
    }
 };

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    sendText(v.getId());
    Log.i("SndBtn_ID & TAG>", "ID:" + v.getId() + ", TAG:" + v.getTag());
 }

 private void sendText(int index) {
    EditText textVw = (EditText) realViewSwitcher.getChildAt(index).findViewWithTag("chat_msg_text" + index);
    String text = textVw.getText().toString();

    Log.i("MSG>>>", ":" + text);

    if (!text.equals("")) {

        TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout) realViewSwitcher.getChildAt(index).findViewWithTag("chat_table" + index);

        // scVw=(ScrollView)realViewSwitcher.getChildAt(index).findViewWithTag("chat_scVw"+index);
        TableRow rowMsg = new TableRow(this);

        TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        // params1.span = 2;
        rowMsg.setLayoutParams(params1);

        /* layout that hold one complete row(i.e.,image, message & line separator). */
        LinearLayout rowChild = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowChild.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rowChild.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //rowChild.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        /* layout that hold image & message. */
        LinearLayout rowChildData = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowChildData.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        rowChildData.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        rowChildData.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        /* layout that show the separator line. */
        LinearLayout rowChildSeparator = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowChildSeparator.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1)); 
        rowChildSeparator.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        //rowChildSeparator.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

        /* Image icon showing that this msg is of. */
        ImageView nxtTo = new ImageView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams nxtParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        nxtParam.topMargin=6;
        nxtParam.gravity=Gravity.TOP;
        nxtTo.setLayoutParams(nxtParam);//(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        nxtTo.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_arrow));

        TextView msg1 = new TextView(this);
        msg1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        msg1.setText(text);
        msg1.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
        msg1.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        msg1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

        TableRow.LayoutParams paramsMsg = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
        paramsMsg.span = 1;
        paramsMsg.weight = 1;

        TableRow.LayoutParams paramsImg = new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsImg.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

        ImageView img1 = new ImageView(this);
        img1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(30, 30));
        img1.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));

        rowChildData.addView(img1);
        rowChildData.addView(nxtTo);
        rowChildData.addView(msg1);

        rowChild.addView(rowChildData);
        rowChild.addView(rowChildSeparator);

        rowMsg.addView(rowChild, paramsMsg);

        tbl.addView(rowMsg);

    }

    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    textVw.setText(null);
  }
 }
```

i gone through `ListView` in [*Transcript Mode*](http://www.mubasheralam.com/tutorials/android/listview-transcript-mode) & [*how update UI from background services*](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/). I am working to built a simple multi-user chat application having separate chat window for each user like gTalk(google talk) the default application on android.

when i am using list view then in this case i am not getting how to update the adapter from background service or when i send new message(how to make different multiple adapters dynamically & update them). Now i am using `TableView` & add one row in it dynamically when i click on send button or on background `Service` *sendBroadcast*.

i am confused that which is better to use `ListView` or `TableView`...?

Finally, what i trying to do is, how do i build chat window that is having three button on the top & multiple chat windows like the [***skype`s***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAkgX.jpg) chat window that can be switched from one to another respectively.**?** 
would appreciate any example code, link or pointer that help me to solve this problem!

Answer (score 2):

**UI**

I would create the UI in xml.

- Define my `ListView` in *chat.xml*, remember that the id of your `ListView` needs to be `@android:id/list`.
- Create a *chat_row.xml* with two different layouts, one for outgoing messages and one for incoming.

You will need a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) for the text background (actually tow, one for incoming and one for outgoing).

**Code**

- Inherit from [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and set the *chat.xml* as *content view*.
- Store your chat messages in a *Sqlite* database.
- Create a custom [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) and set it as list adapter.
- In the `bindView` function for your `CursorAdapter` hide/show the correct layout from your *chat_row.xml* and set all values (values which you will get from the database).

**Links**

Custom CursorAdaptors - http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable response! It works but What exactly i need is to have one list of user to whom i can `chat`. the application that i am building is a `Tabbed` based application. when i click on any item in the `list view` having user to whom i can chat then it open one `separate chat window` for this user & same as this open separate chat windows for other users. I edit my question above, I pleased you to gone through the `screen shots` newly added. I would greatly appreciate your response in this query, Hope you don't mind to help me to short out this problem.

Comment: You want to open a separate tab for every person you start a chat with?

Comment: i Want to add one new chat window in to the same layout that can be scrolled between these different chat windows. It is on the same tab & in the same layout. How can achieve this? @tidbeck

Comment: I would use two different activities, one for all contacts and one to show a specific conversation. Found this [Navigate different activities within a TabView](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=5424397F3130CE7769FF47DD67742911?recipeId=1693&recipeFrom=ViewTOC) regarding switching content view.

Comment: Thanks for ur response,I tried these things but did not get the solution, i also tried the thing you have mentioned but in following way : I built one class(TabGp) that extends `ActivityGroup` & then i `extends` all other Classes that are bind with the different tabs of my `TabHost` by this class(TabGp) & start other different activities by calling `startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent)` method of TabGp. I need similar as shown in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=9lN4N3BhqMc#!) link & please look at the video after 58 sec onword when chatting start. @tidbeck

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do that. Sounds like another question.